# Using HTML5 Canvas to parse an image into a tileset

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm attempting to parse a tileset image (of type .png) into an array. I've got a test canvas that I'm using to draw it to first, then I am extracting the image info from it. When I run this code, it throws "Uncaught TypeError: Type error." I was able to log that this.mainTiles is empty. Any ideas? I don't know all the subtleties of Canvas yet, so I'm stuck. Thanks for the help! (Also, you can ignore the last line at the end, I was just using it to test--but I wanted to illustrate that it doesn't work).

```
function TileSet() {
    this.tileSheets = [];
    this.mainTiles = [];
    this.tileHeight = 32;
    this.tileWidth = 32;




    this.addSpriteSheet = function (spriteSheetLoc, name) {

        var tileSheet = new Image();
        try {
            tileSheet.src = spriteSheetLoc;
        }
        catch(err) {
            dMode.Log("Invalid TileSheet Src ( TileSet.setSpriteSheet() Failed ); ERR: " +  err);
        }


        tempContext.drawImage(tileSheet, 0, 0);


        var tilesX = tempContext.width / this.tileWidth;
        var tilesY = tempContext.height / this.tileHeight;

        for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++) {
            for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++) {
                // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
                this.mainTiles.push(tempContext.getImageData(j*this.tileWidth, i*this.tileHeight, this.tileWidth, this.tileHeight));
            }
        }


        context.putImageData(this.mainTiles[0], 5, 5);



    }
```

Edit: Here are how the canvases and such are defined:

```
var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("tempCanvas");
var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


var Tiles = new TileSet;
//this is the line it gets stuck at


Tiles.addSpriteSheet("resources/tiles/tilea2.png");
```

Edit 2: After markE's answer, here's the latest update. Still feel as though I'm missing a fundamental property regarding .onload.

```
function TileSet() {
    this.Tiles = [];
    this.tileHeight = 32;
    this.tileWidth = 32;
    this.tileCount = 4;




    this.addSpriteSheet = function (spriteSheetLoc, name) {

        var tileSheet = new Image();
        tileSheet.onload = function() {
            tempCanvas.width = tileSheet.width;
            tempCanvas.height = tileSheet.height;
            tempContext.drawImage(tileSheet, 0, 0);



           for (var t=0;t<this.tileCount;t++) {
       this.Tiles[t]=tempContext.getImageData(t*this.tileWidth,t*32,this.tileWidth,tileSheet.height);
               dMode.Log(this.Tiles);
           }


            context.putImageData(this.Tiles[this.Tiles.length-1],0,0);
            dMode.Log(this.Tiles);
        }

        tileSheet.src = spriteSheetLoc;
}
```

Comment: Could you show how `tempContext` is defined?

Comment: Sure thing. See edits for the code.

Comment: Try replacing `tempContext.width` and `tempContext.height` with `tempCanvas.width` and `tempCanvas.height` respectively. I don't believe contexts have width/height.

Comment: That fixed it! I didn't realize I should use the canvas directly in order to access its width--I thought I had to use the context. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it worked!
If you don't mind, I will post my comment as an answer, I'd appreciate if you accepted it.

Comment: Of course. This is the first time I've used stackoverflow, so I'll figure out how!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's how to parse a spritesheet into an array of separate canvas imageData**

I have some working code that does what you want to do.

I didn't have your "resources/tiles/tilea2.png" so I used my own "monstersArun.png" which is a 10 across spritesheet of 64x64 tiles.

You can modify this code to fit your spritesheet layout ( rows x columns and tile size).

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var tileCount=10;
    var tiles=new Array();
    var tileWidth;
    var t;
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
      canvas.width=img.width;
      canvas.height=img.height;
      tileWidth=img.width/tileCount;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

      for(var t=0;t<tileCount;t++){
            tiles[t]=ctx.getImageData(t*tileWidth,0,tileWidth,img.height);
      }

      // just a test
      // draw the last tiles[] into another canvas
      var canvasTile=document.getElementById("canvasTile");
      var ctxTile=canvasTile.getContext("2d");
      canvasTile.width=tileWidth;
      canvasTile.height=canvas.height;
      ctxTile.putImageData(tiles[tiles.length-1],0,0);
    }
    img.src="monsterarun.png";

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br/>
    <canvas id="canvasTile" width=64 height=64></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Edit--to include Juan Mendes good idea give help on coding problem]**

Also, as I look at your code...here:

```
tileSheet.src = spriteSheetLoc;
```

This causes your image to load.  That loading takes time to do, so javascript starts loading the image, but it also **immediately goes on to your next line of code**.  As a result, your code below tries to use the image before it's available--no good!

So you should give javascript a chance to fully load your image before processing the rest of your code.  You do this using the onload method of Image like this:

```
var tileSheet = new Image();
tileSheet.onload=function(){

    // put ALL you code that depends on the image being fully loaded here

}
tileSheet.src = spriteSheetLoc;
```

Notice how you put tileSheet.src *after* the onload function.  In reality, javascript executes tilesheet.src and then *goes back* to execute all the code in the onload block!

[Edit again -- complete code]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("tempCanvas");
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


    // create a new TileSet
    var Tiles = new TileSet();

    // parse a spritesheet into tiles
    //Tiles.addSpriteSheet("resources/tiles/tilea2.png","anyName");
    Tiles.addSpriteSheet("houseIcon.png","anyName");


    function TileSet() {
        this.Tiles = [];
        this.tileHeight = 32;
        this.tileWidth = 32;
        this.tileCount = 4;

        this.addSpriteSheet = function (spriteSheetLoc, name) {

            var me=this;  // me==this==TileSet

            var tileSheet = new Image();
            tileSheet.onload = function() {

                // calculate the rows/cols in the spritesheet
                // tilesX=rows, tilesY=cols
                var tilesX = tileSheet.width / me.tileWidth;
                var tilesY = tileSheet.height / me.tileHeight;

                // set the spritesheet canvas to spritesheet.png size
                // then draw spritesheet.png into the canvas
                tempCanvas.width = tileSheet.width;
                tempCanvas.height = tileSheet.height;
                tempContext.drawImage(tileSheet, 0, 0);
                for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++) {

                    for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++) {

                        // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
                        me.Tiles.push(tempContext.getImageData(j*me.tileWidth, i*me.tileHeight, me.tileWidth, me.tileHeight));
                    }
                }

                // this is just a test
                // display the last tile in a canvas
                context.putImageData(me.Tiles[me.Tiles.length-1],0,0);

            }
            // load the spritesheet .png into tileSheet Image()
            tileSheet.src = spriteSheetLoc;
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="tempCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br/>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but it'd be nice to explain what's wrong  with the OP's coded

Comment: @Juan Mendes: Thanks for the prodding, I'm usually more helpful...added help for OP to my answer  :)

Comment: This is certainly a cleaner solution, and makes sense--but for some reason it's just not working for me. Sorry to inundate you with questions, I feel as though there is something fundamental about this that I need to get straight regarding the .onload function once and for all. I've posted the latest iteration to the original post.

Comment: @Taylor Hill,  Here is your code in working condition.  A couple of notes: within tileSheet.onload the "this" refers to the tileSheet Image()--not to your TileSet object (that's the point of var me=this;).  Your TileSet object relies on tempContext to be defined outside the object.  Instead, you'll want to create your canvas inside TileSet like this: var myTempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas"); Then create a context for myTempCanvas.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm amazed at how helpful this community is.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `tempContext.width` and `tempContext.height` with `tempCanvas.width` and `tempCanvas.height`, respectively. I don't believe contexts have width/height.